# unit testing issue with IDataProtectionProvider in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to unit test a my action method in my ASP.NET Core MVC controller, but I get this error, please help.

> Message:
> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: POSModels.CryptoParamsProtector.
> Could not find a parameterless constructor.
>
> Stack Trace:
> ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments) ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)   CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments) line 62   Mock`1.InitializeInstance() line 311
> Mock`1.OnGetObject() line 325   Mock.get_Object() line 179   Mock`1.get_Object() line 283
> UnitTypesControllerTests.initController(Object obj) line 80
> UnitTypesControllerTests.IndexTest() line 86

This is my unit test code and error is thrown from the last line in `initController` method.

```
namespace PWEB.Controllers.Tests
{
    using Xunit;

    public class UnitTypesControllerTests
    {
        private Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> contextAccessor;
        private UnitTypesController unitTypesController;
        private Mock<NetCorePOSSystemConfig> config;
        private Mock<IHttpClientFactory> httpClientFactory;
        private Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<NetCorePOSSystemConfig>> configure;
        private Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext> mockHttpContext;
        private Mock<MockHttpMessageHandler> mock;
        private Mock<CryptoParamsProtector> cryptoParams;
        PaginationEntity<UnitTypeModel> paginationEntity = new PaginationEntity<UnitTypeModel>()
        {
            Items = new List<UnitTypeModel>(),
            MetaData = new PaginationMetaData()
            {
                Count = 1,
                TotalItemCount = 1,
                PageNumber = 1,
                FirstItemOnPage = 1,
                HasNextPage = false,
                HasPreviousPage = false,
                IsFirstPage = true,
                IsLastPage = false,
                LastItemOnPage = 1,
                PageCount = 1,
                PageSize = 20
            }
        };

        public UnitTypesControllerTests()
        {
            cryptoParams = new Mock<CryptoParamsProtector>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            mock = new Mock<MockHttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        }

        private void initController(object obj)
        {
            string value = "1";
            byte[] val = new byte[] { 1 };             
            mock.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()).ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
            }).Verifiable();
            var client = new HttpClient(mock.Object)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            };

            httpClientFactory = new Moq.Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
            httpClientFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(client);

            config = new Mock<NetCorePOSSystemConfig>();
            contextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            mockHttpContext = new Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext>();

            Mock<ISession> mocks = new Mock<ISession>();
            mocks.Setup(c => c.Set("JWToken", It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Callback<string, byte[]>((k, v) => value = v.ToString());
            mocks.Setup(v => v.TryGetValue("JWToken", out val)).Returns(true);
            mockHttpContext.Setup(v => v.Session).Returns(mocks.Object);
            contextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(mockHttpContext.Object);
            configure = new Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<NetCorePOSSystemConfig>>();
            unitTypesController = new UnitTypesController(cryptoParams.Object, httpClientFactory.Object, configure.Object, contextAccessor.Object);
        }

        [Fact()]
        public void IndexTest()
        { 
                initController(paginationEntity);
                ViewResult result = unitTypesController.Index(1).Result as ViewResult;
                mock.Verify();
                Assert.IsType<StaticPagedList<UnitTypeModel>>(result.ViewData.Model);
            
        }
}
```

My controller is look like this,

```
public class UnitTypesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly IOptions<NetCorePOSSystemConfig> _options; 
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
        private readonly CryptoParamsProtector cryptoParams;
       

        public UnitTypesController(CryptoParamsProtector paramsProtector, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IOptions<NetCorePOSSystemConfig> config, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
        {
           //code          
             ..................
        }
}
```

encryption class look like this,

```
public class CryptoParamsProtector
    {
            IDataProtector _protector;

            public CryptoParamsProtector(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
            {
                _protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(GetType().FullName);
            }

            // ...........
    }
```

Comment: The issue is clear from the exception message. You do not have a parameterless constructor for the instantiation of the class. You ONLY have a constructor with a parameter set. 

Create one, that doesn't have any, and implement a check on your code that _protector is initialized. Or instatiate one manually.

Or pass a parameter into your instantiation of the object it is trying to create an instance of.

Answer (score 0):

when mocked the parameters in the constructor of CryptoParamsProtector, then issue was fixed

```
        private Mock<IDataProtectionProvider> mockIDataProtectionProvider = new Mock<IDataProtectionProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        private Mock<IDataProtector> mockDpro = new Mock<IDataProtector>();

        public UnitTypesControllerTests()
        {
            mockIDataProtectionProvider.Setup(v=>v.CreateProtector(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockDpro.Object);
            cryptoParams = new Mock<CryptoParamsProtector>(MockBehavior.Strict, mockIDataProtectionProvider.Object);
            mock = new Mock<MockHttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        }
```